# How to fix EnvEval error in CLIPS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, clips, expert-system

I'm trying to use CLIPS framework for iOS with Swift. I've done all the configuration and the CLIPS program run well and complete the computation successfully.

Clips code:

```
(deftemplate travel-banchmark
   (slot name)
   (slot value))

(deftemplate permutation
   (multislot values))

(deffacts initial
   (number-of-place 3)
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value torino))
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value roma))
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value milano))
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value venezia))
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value napoli)))

(defrule first-in-permutation
   (number-of-place ~0)
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value ?city))
   =>
   (assert (permutation (values ?city))))

(defrule next-in-permutation
   (number-of-place ?k)
   ?p <- (permutation (values $?cities))
   (test (< (length$ ?cities) ?k))
   (travel-banchmark (name place) (value ?city))
   (test (not (member$ ?city ?cities)))
   =>
   (assert (permutation (values ?cities ?city))))

(defrule cleanup
   (declare (salience -5))
   (number-of-place ?k)
   ?p <- (permutation (values $?cities))
   (test (< (length$ ?cities) ?k))
   =>
   (retract ?p))
```

Swift code:

```swift
EnvWatch(clipsEnv,"activations");
EnvWatch(clipsEnv,"facts");
EnvLoad(clipsEnv,filePath);
EnvReset(clipsEnv);
EnvRun(clipsEnv,-1);
EnvPrintRouter(clipsEnv,WPROMPT,"Test");
let expression = "(find-all-facts ((?f permutation)) TRUE)";
var outputValue:DATA_OBJECT_PTR?;
EnvEval(clipsEnv, expression, outputValue)
```

During the evaluation of `EnvEval` I got this error:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` without any other explanation.

Any suggestion on what can I check? Do you need other pieces of information​?

Edit:
I've changed these two lines:

```
var outputValue: DATA_OBJECT = DATA_OBJECT.init();
EnvEval(clipsEnv, expression, &outputValue)
```

Now this piece of code works but I have trouble to understand why the identifiers like `GetValue` are unresolved

Comment: Are you using some kind of wrapper to embed the CLIPS C code into Swift? What's the code behind that DATA_OBJECT.init() call? GetValue is a macro in the CLIPS source code, not a function, so perhaps that has something to do with the identifier being unresolved.

Comment: Swift sees every header exposed in the umbrella header of the CLIPS framework, so I can use a lot of function directly from Swift without any problem. The problem is what you said, I can't use the macros in Swift. What I'm now thinking is to create an objective-c class with some functions that use the clips macro and call that function in swift (not so nice)

Comment: I haven't done any Swift programming so I don't know why the macros wouldn't show up. You might also consider using the 6.4 release. The API for retrieving values has been overhauled and doesn't rely on macros.